# Check if $_FILES or $_POST was passed

Tags: php, post

I have a website were you can **either** upload an image or upload some text. Your can't do both. I will then pass which ever one was uploaded to a php file. What's the best, most efficient way of checking which one was passed?

The first thing that came to mind, was to create both variables, `$_FILES` and `$_POST`, then check if one is empty. If `$_FILES` is empty, then that means text was passed to php.

That won't work, because what if the user really did upload an image, but for some reason it didn't go through. php will then think that text was passed, and it won't work.

How can I check in php which was passed, `$_POST` or `$_FILES`?

Comment: You cannot "create" them, they are set or not. `if (!empty($_POST["someindex"]))` will do.

Comment: No. That's an incorrect assumption. If `$_FILES` is empty, then the user didn't attempt to upload any file, as the browser didn't pass one along. If you need to tell the user which files are acceptable, etc, then you need to use some javascript to check the file type association prior to uploading. Then you can always safely check `if(empty($_FILES))` safely.

Comment: You can start by using `if(!empty($_POST['var']) && !empty($_FILES['file'])){ echo "You can't do both"; }`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would alter the text to read "We could have had it all" (inspired by the wonderful Adèle...)

Comment: @Jan *haha!* indeed Jan. Adèle is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `&&` operator with mixed conditionals:

```
if(!empty($_POST['var']) && !empty($_FILES['file'])){ 
   echo "You can't do both"; 
}

elseif(!empty($_POST['var']) && empty($_FILES['file'])){
   echo "Allowed";
}

elseif(!empty($_FILES['file']) && empty($_POST['var'])){
   echo "Allowed";
}

else{
   echo "Choose at least one";
}
```